# JSP file doesn't run in browser with Netbeans 9.0

Tags: jsp, runtime, netbeans-9

[image]

When I click "Run File", it doesn't run and it's not showing any status bar at the bottom.

The same thing for the HTML file. The file .java and other things are running normally. I'm using Netbeans 9.0.
When I was working with Netbeans 8.0.2, the problem didn't happen.

Comment: Check in netbeans community instead https://netbeans.org/community/

Comment: thank you . i will ask my question in the community